# Loop through cells to create a sequence

Tags: excel, vba

I am having difficulties in trying to loop my cell column values to fulfill a series that copies data depending on the count of data. This is what I need to do

```
A1 AA     B1 2     C1 AA
A2 AA     B2 2     C2 AB
A3 AB     B3 2     C3 AC
A4 AB     B4 1     C4 AD
A5 AC     B5       C5
A6 AC     B6       C6
A7 AD     B7       B7
```

1. Column B tells how many times C will show in A
2. I need to loop Columns B and C to create the series in Column A

How can I loop through cells to display the values in series while ignoring the blank cells?

I tried looping one cell, but I cannot create a loop through each cell.

```
Sub loop_cells()
Dim var As Long
Set Rng = Range("C1")
var = Range("B2").Value
i = 1

Do Until i = var
Range("A1:A" & var).Value = Rng
i = i + 1

Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a VBA Solution this should work:

```
Sub doSomeLooping()
Dim WS As Worksheet, aCell As Range, i As Long, j As Long
    Set WS = ActiveSheet 'or whatever.

ReDim SomeValues(j)

For Each aCell In Intersect(WS.Range("C:C"), WS.UsedRange).Cells
    If Not IsEmpty(aCell) Then
        For i = 1 To aCell.Offset(0, -1).Value
            ReDim Preserve SomeValues(j)
            SomeValues(j) = aCell.Value
            j = j + 1
        Next i
    End If
Next aCell

WS.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(SomeValues), 1).Value = _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(SomeValues)

End Sub
```

I also think you can get what you need with just a formula, if you have [spill range](https://www.contextures.com/excelspillformulaexamples.html). Consider this function in cell `A1`.

```
=FILTERXML("<x><y>"&SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(TEXTJOIN("",FALSE,FILTER(REPT(C:C&"!",B:B),B:B<>"")),LEN(TEXTJOIN("",FALSE,FILTER(REPT(C:C&"!",B:B),B:B<>"")))-1),"!","</y><y>")&"</y></x>","//y")
```

Comment: Instead of ReDim'ming each iteration, you could use `ReDim SomeValues(Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Intersect(WS.Range("C:C"),WS.UsedRange)))` outside perhaps? Which would be better performance wise?

Comment: @GokhanAycan, good call and I did consider leveraging something like that but decided not to because that limits the overall value of my answer to other viewers. That summation method is highly specific to this question,  and not likely to be in other people looking to do something with an array.  I did include a formula solution instead... anyway thanks for the suggestion.